# A strangely frustrating Java Syntax error

Tags: java, eclipse, syntax-error

I just can't figure out what is wrong here, I always get the error 
"Syntax error on  token "=", Expression expected after this token",
 but I just cannot figure out what this means.

```
 import java.util.Arrays;

 public class Zeitmessen {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int zahl = 1;
    while (zahl <= 8) {

        long zeit = System.currentTimeMillis();
        double[][] quicktipp = new double[zahl][6];
        for (int i = 0; i < quicktipp[0].length; i++) {
            double random = (int) (Math.random() * 45);
            zahl++;
            quicktipp = [zahl][6];
            quicktipp[0][i] = random;
            zahl++;
            quicktipp[1][i] = random;
            zahl++;
            quicktipp[2][i] = random;
            zahl++;
            quicktipp[3][i] = random;
            zahl++;
            quicktipp[4][i] = random;
            zahl++;
            quicktipp[5][i] = random;
            zahl++;
            quicktipp[6][i] = random;
            zahl++;
            quicktipp[7][i] = random;






        }

        for (int x = 0; x < quicktipp.length; x++) {
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(quicktipp[x]));

        }
        zeit = System.currentTimeMillis() - zeit;
        System.out.println(zeit);
        System.out.println("");

        }

}
```

}

```
     quicktipp = [zahl][6];
```

here I get the error

Can somebody please help me?

Comment: array = [1][6]; is invalid java.

Comment: I'm curious: What did you expect that line to do? What was your intention?

Answer (score 1):

`quicktipp = [zahl][6];` doesn't make any sense. I suspect you're thinking you need to initialize the array at that point or something, but you don't, you've already done that with `double[][] quicktipp = new double[zahl][6];`. So you can just delete that line and go straight to your `quicktipp[0][i] = random;` code.

Comment: (There may well be logic errors in the code as well, but that's the syntax error.)